# is it possible to supply argument when running Rmarkdown in the command line?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am trying to create different sets of report based on a template.

1. is it possible to run this report from a command line rather than running it via RStudio (knit PDF)?
2. I have a vector called app where I run this report for each app and output the value. Is it possible to supply app via the command line option when running this report from the command line? Rather than having app in the Rmarkdown, I need to know if I can supply this as an argument?
3. Every time I run this, pdf file name is the same. How can I change this so that pdf file names is the same as the app value?

   ---

   ````
   title: "Application Report"

   date: "July 13th, 2017"
   header-includes:
      - \usepackage{longtable}
      - \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
      - \usepackage{colortbl}
      - \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   output:
     pdf_document:
       fig_caption: yes
       fig_height: 6
       fig_width: 7
       highlight: zenburn
       number_sections: yes
       toc: yes
       toc_depth: 3
   keep_tex: yes
   tables: yes
   fontsize: 15
   ---

   ```{r message=FALSE, results = 'asis', echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.width=12, fig.height=10}

   app<-c("Web","DB)


   for (i in app){

       cat(paste("# ",app, " - Application","\n"))
   }
   ````

Comment: Explore the `params` option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short Answers:

1. Yes
2. Yes
3. Yes

Example: I will use two files and a command line example.  Using a makefile or extending the `knit-application-report.R` script will simplify your workflow.

First file:  `application-report.Rmd`  I've simplified from your example file for this posting.  The important thing to knot is that the variable `app` has been defined.  This variable will be used in the report title and can be used elsewhere in the report.

````
---
title: "`r app` Report"
date: "`r date()`"
output: pdf_document
---

This is the report for the `r app` application.

```{r}
# do stuff
```
````

File 2: `knit-application-report.R`  The call to `commandArgs`, with `trailingOnly = TRUE` pass command line arguments into the R script.  The name of the application is passed in as the first and only argument.  That value is stored in the `app` variable which will then be used in the call to `rmarkdown::render` and used when evaluating the .Rmd file.

```
# file: knit-application-report.R
#
# Commandline Arguments:
# 1. appliction a character string for the app

app <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)

rmarkdown::render(input = "application-report.Rmd",
                  output_file = paste0(app, ".pdf"))
```

The command line looks like this (from my linux command line).

```
me@mycomputer:~$ Rscript knit-application-report.R MyApplication


processing file: application-report.Rmd
  |................................                                 |  50%
   inline R code fragments

  |.................................................................| 100%
label: unnamed-chunk-1

output file: application-report.knit.md

/usr/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS application-report.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output MyApplication.pdf --template /home/pdewitt/R-dev/R-3.4.1/library/rmarkdown/rmd/latex/default-1.17.0.2.tex --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --variable 'geometry:margin=1in'

Output created: MyApplication.pdf
```

Note that the output is the named report `MyApplication.pdf` which looks like this:

[image]

Comment: this is really great. How do I use app in the chunks in rmarkdown? ```r{}  ```

Comment: chunk options are R expressions.  You could set `echo = app == "MyApplication"`, for example, to echo the chunk only for the 'MyApplication' and suppress the code from the report for all other applications.

Comment: I need to reference app in the chunks. How can I reference the value of app in r chunk?

Comment: `app` is a variable in the workspace.  You can use it as you would any other variable.  `if (app == "MyApplication") { } else { }` can be used to control what is done in a chunk for a given application.